# Executing a simple Python script not working with Sidekiq

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

```
class SeedWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    `python lib/assets/python_scripts/seed.py`
  end
end
```

I am trying to execute this from terminal like so:

```
bundle exec SeedWorker.perform_async()
```

I have a Redis server and Sidekiq running as well as a Rails server. The script works fine by itself, but I am wondering if this is even possible.  Also Sinatra is running too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`SeedWorker.perform_async()` is not an executable---that will not work. Also, Sidekiq is already running, but it may not have loaded your worker file. Last, Sidekiq just requires Redis. Rails and Sinatra are not related to your problem.

That statement will work in an environment like `irb`. Alternatively you can use the `sidekiq` executable:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -r <path to your worker file>
```

How about following up the [good documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started) provided with Sidekiq?